# Cloudant - apply a view/mapReduce to a geospatial query

Tags: couchdb, geospatial, cloudant

HI I'm new to cloudant (and couch and asking questions on stackoverflow so I hope I manage to be vaguely clear about what I'm asking ) and I'm trying to do probably the second most basic geo task but am hitting a dead end.

I've got a database of docs which are geojson objects, I've created an index so I can query for intersections etc but it seems the only options I have in the url is the format=legacy (gives me the ids) and the format=geojson and the include_docs parameter - what I'd like to do is give back a particular view of the result set - I'm not interested in the geometry of the object (which is a big lump of data and it's likely that a number of other properties may be in the document that I'd rather filter out)

is there a correct way to do this in a single api call or do I need to fetch the doc ids (legacy format) and then issue a second query to bring back my chosen 'view' for each document id given in the result of format=legacy response

Thanks

Comment: When you say  that you want to bring back your "chosen view", what do you mean? If you query only the ids, how can you "filter" them to only choose some of them?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me - after a spate of mongo I was struggling with the whole 'rows' and keys/values part of it - the rows thing makes sense now but I'm still a little phased by exactly what the key value role is/does so at least for the moment im avoiding using it!